# Sockets writing and reading but no data is received

Tags: python, scripting

I've written a very simple script for Blender, to test UNIX UDP sockets for a bigger app. I've got a external script that feeds data into a socket, and another inside Blender (with Always Sensor and Python Controller) that first creates the socket, and then reads from it. The problem is that there is connexion, and data is extracted from the socket, because the buffer never fills, but  "data, addr = GL.s.recvfrom(1024)" returns nothing.

**Writer:**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_address = '/tmp/index'

angle = 0
while True:
    if angle == 0:
        angle = 45
        data = str(angle)
    else:
        angle = 0
        data = str(angle)
    s.sendto(data, client_address)
    print("Sent " + data)
```

**Reader**

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
hand = cont.owner
temp_address = '/tmp/index'


if not hand['Once']: # Game property so the socket is only created once
    GL.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    GL.s.setblocking(0)

    # Make sure the socket does not already exist
    try:
        os.unlink(temp_address) # Remove (delete) the file path
    except OSError:
        if os.path.exists(temp_address):
            raise

    GL.s.bind(temp_address)
    hand['Once'] = True

try:
    data, addr = GL.s.recvfrom(1024)
    print("Data received!" + data)
except:
    print("No data yet!")
```

The Writer keeps writing, and the Reader keeps saying "No data yet".

Comment: I've seen that the problem is not in the socket but in the way python treates the exception. There is data stored in `data` but it raises an error in the `recvfrom()` so the `except` block is executed